# Strange red light coming out of headphone jack on Macbook Pro running Ubuntu

Tags: macos, ubuntu, audio, fiber

I have a dual-boot machine running Yosemite and Ubuntu. I do not get the light when I am on Yosemite, but when I am on Ubuntu, a strange red light appears.

Comment: That's the devil in your machine.  He's also responsible for all of the problems you experience using it.  The only way to solve the problem is with an exorcist. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's an optical "toslink" output built into the headphone jack.

I don't know why it's enabled in Ubuntu, and not in Mac OS X.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.head-fi.org/t/614078/does-the-retina-macbookpro-have-optical-out). Also my source for the information provided, by the way.

Comment: OS X is smart enough to save power (and avoid user bewilderment) by only switching it into TOSLINK mode when something's plugged in that isn't an analog headphone plug. Sounds like Ubuntu is just blindly running the TOSLINK transmit LED all the time.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is a mini-[TOSLINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TOSLINK) connector.

- TOSLINK is a fiber-optic digital audio connection system used to carry [S/PDIF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S/PDIF) signals. The mini-TOSLINK jack is often combined with a normal 3.5mm audio jack. On your system, it is combined with the main audio channels; on my laptop, the jack is used for the side audio channels. Many TVs and video game consoles have TOSLINK connectors as well.
- TOSLINK is often used in home theater systems but is being replaced by HDMI, which can also carry audio and has much higher bandwidth.
- The image below depicts a full-size TOSLINK cable; mini-TOSLINK simply uses a smaller connector and adapters are available.

[image: TOSLINK cable]
*[Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Fiber_optic_illuminated.jpg)*

Comment: I'd also add chances are its a *combo* 3.5mm/toslink port